# R - get help in browser instead of the in-build R helper

Tags: r

I've seen two different behaviours of R help (when you type `?density` for example):

- help is open in your default browser
- help is open in in-build R helper (window within R)

I currently have the second behaviour, but I would like to open the help in the browser. Can I somehow easily switch between these two behaviours? Without re-installation. Ideally, setting some R option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
options(help_type = "html") # open help in browser
options(help_type = "text") # open help internally
```

Comment: Thank @January and Roman Lustrik for help - the problem with server was caused by me having the external proxy set in my browser...

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have help_type = "html" and still the help opens on R helper. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8):

If anyone is having this problem in OSX you may need to follow this process (apologies I can't remember where I found this):

1. edit `/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/R/Options.R` (e.g. `nano ...`)
2. comment out the entry as follows:

```
# options(browser = function(url)
# {
# .Call("rs_browseURL", url) ;
# })
```

Comment: Its meant for general benefit. The solution doesn't exist anywhere else in SO (as I discovered the hard way yesterday) and this seems the closest matching page.

Comment: Thanks for this - RStudio's internal help pane was making me nuts. On Windows, this file is under `Program Files\RStudio\R`.

Comment: Glad it helps. You just need to be aware to repeat the process whenever you update to new version of RStudio. Not sure if base R IDE has an equivalent procedure.

Comment: Every now and then I return to this page to recall the process, and every time am slightly shocked by the rudeness of @TMS's first comment above..  It's not even as if he/she specified an OS!

Comment: geotheory my comment is not rude, I just point out that you are probably posting solution to some problem I didn't even mention. *"If anyone is having this problem"*... which problem? I didn't mention any. I am just asking a question. To me it's not clear at all what you are answering here.

Comment: Well it is a possible solution for RStudio users - not a small R demographic - but admittedly not base R.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use help.start() function. Then paste the URL from console into any browser, e.g. when I run help.start() the following is shown in console:

> help.start()
>   If nothing happens, you should open
>   ‘http://127.0.0.1:17741/doc/html/index.html’ yourself

So I copy http://127.0.0.1:17741/doc/html/index.html into Chrome or Firefox and enjoy R Help in browser.