# Rstudio - How do I open help files in browser?

Tags: r, rstudio

How do I open the help files in the browser instead of the internal Rstudio viewer?

I have ready set the following option `options(help_type="html")` in .Rprofile

And have added

```
# custom browseURL implementation
options(browser = function(url)
{
    .Call("rs_browseURL", url) ;
})
```

to options.R

Everytime I update Rstudio this preference is changed.

Comment: Set options like these in a `.Rprofile` file, to be run on startup. See `?Startup`.

Comment: @MikaelJagan I should've mentioned, I have a ready done that, no luck!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21296928/12685768) answer says to comment out those lines in the RStudio file `Options.R`, not insert them.

Comment: Though, instead of modifying `Options.R`, why not override the RStudio setting by adding `options(browser = /path/to/browser)` to your `.Rprofile`? I'd expect your `.Rprofile` to take precedence (i.e., to be loaded last).

Comment: @MikaelJagan thank you you help me find the solution, the code to comment out has been changed a bit so that's why couldn't find it. Here I am posting the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that this section of the code in Options.R needs to be commented out. This code is slightly different from the code that was used before which is mentioned in a previous answer.

```
# custom browseURL implementation.
# .rs.setOption("browser", function(url)
# {
#    .Call("rs_browseURL", url, PACKAGE = "(embedding)")
# })
```

Also make sure you have set `options(help_type="html")` in your Rprofile.site which contains all the preferences set at startup

Comment: On Windows `Options.R` is here: `C:\Program Files\RStudio\R\Options.R`